# How to convert a div css line to django template line for this particular line?

Tags: css, django, django-views, django-templates, django-static

I want to convert a particular template  line containing  and inline css into django template line which will show the static files too. The template line is

```
<div class="single-welcome-slides bg-img bg-overlay jarallax" style="background-image: url(img/bg-img/1.jpg);">
```

What will be the django static template line to load the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe You can try something like this

```
<div class="single-welcome-slides bg-img bg-overlay jarallax" style="background-image: url({% static 'img/bg-img/1.jpg' %});" />
```

Happy Coding!